# Working cordova app with mobileFirst adapters

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a cordova application and I have registered my application with IBM MobileFirst foundation service instance. And I have also created two http javascript adapters as well in my application but how can I use those adapters to retrieve the data or either post the data, just not getting that. I have tried several solution for that but non of them worked. Please help me resolve it as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke adapter endpoints from your cordova application with the `WLResourceRequest` API.

[This](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/) tutorial explains on how to use `WLResourceRequest` API in MobileFirst application for accessing adapter resource.

Comment: I have Jason data ni my application can I pass that json data from my adapter by creating api in that either "GET" or "POST" "PUT" or " DELETE" method in my http JavaScript adapter.

Comment: @Alok Yes, Please go through the tutorial which i mentioned in the above answer.